# Can Sphinx be configured to give more weight to certain fields?

Tags: search, full-text-search, sphinx

Hey, so I'm wondering if it's possible for Sphinx to weight certain fields of document over others in its results.  For example, if I did a search for `the rock show`, is it possible to configure sphinx to give much higher precedence to a song named `the rock show` over a song which has `the rock show` in its lyrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **SetFieldWeights**

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setfieldweights

Comment: Thanks.  I'm setting one field's weight to 4,000,000 and another field's to 1, but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the order of the results.

The only thing that seems to make a difference is what I have the MatchMode set to, and it seems like Sphinx is ignoring the weight all together.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old but here is a good article from the Sphinx blog on matching and weighting in Sphinx:

[**» How Sphinx relevance ranking works**](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/)